# Opening URL inside visual basic form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I would like to open webpage in VB form, however in ToolBox, there is missing WebBrowser. Could someone help me, where is the problem? I am creating project

[image]

In list of tools there is nothing with

[image]

Comment: The instructions are here: [Get started with WebView2 in WinForms apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are using the correct windows forms?
[This is what I use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfNCc.png)

Comment: Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/"
Process.Start(webAddress)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I believe plocha may translate to desktop.

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser control is not available in .NET5 or later versions. As an alternative, you should use Webview2 control. See : [How to use new WebBrowserControl in .Net 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/269837/how-to-use-new-webbrowsercontrol-in-net-5.html)

If your project only target windows, you can use WebBrowser control by creating a .NET Framework project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot use webview in win forms anymore. Please try this code :)

```
Dim webAddress As String = "http://www.example.com/" \
Process.Start(webAddress)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).